# Не могу разобраться в ошибке в коде, подскажите новичку

Tags: java

Не могу понять в чем проблема. Выдает ошибку в 45 строке в представленном коде. Подскажите, что делаю не так.

```
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
int sum = 0;
boolean error = false;
while(!error){
    if(console.hasNextInt()){
        int namb1 = console.nextInt();
        sum = sum + namb1;
    }
    else (console.hasNextLine()){
        String line = console.nextLine();
        if(line.equals("ENTER")){
            error = true;
        }
    }
System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, не используйте фото в вопросе, код и ошибку можно скинуть текстом

Comment: Пропустили `if` после `else` перед условием.  См. [Условные операторы в Java](https://tproger.ru/articles/uslovnye-operatory-v-java/)

Comment: [Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/385375)

Answer (score 2):

У `else` никогда не было такого, чтобы писались какие-то круглые скобки, проверящие условие..... скорее всего должно быть `else if`